# Creating a df starting from a timestamp value and ending on a timestamp value increment by one hour in Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Can anyone help me to create a data frame were starting and ending timestamp value is given and we need to print all the hour increment by one?

Example 
Starting timestamp: 02-05-2020 01:00

Ending timestamp: 03-05-2020 02:00

So the df should have all those values:

```
02-05-2020 01:00
02-05-2020 02:00
02-05-2020 03:00
02-05-2020 04:00
02-05-2020 05:00
.
.
. 
03-05-2020 02:00
```

Comment: What have you tried already - can you share your code?

Comment: Not able to get the logic

Comment: Check my answer, it gets you the result you want

Comment: @Etisha, can you please check my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below code.

```
scala> val df = Seq(("02-05-2020 01:00","03-05-2020 02:00")).toDF("start","end")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [start: string, end: string]

scala> df.show(false)
+----------------+----------------+
|start           |end             |
+----------------+----------------+
|02-05-2020 01:00|03-05-2020 02:00|
+----------------+----------------+


scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

// Creating UDF to get List of dates.
val dateList = udf((start:String,end: String) => {
      import org.joda.time._
      import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
      val st = DateTime.parse(start,DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"))
      val et = DateTime.parse(end,DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"))
      (0 to Hours.hoursBetween(st,et).getHours)
         .map(hour => st.plusHours(hour).toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")))
        .toList
})


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

dateList: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function2>,ArrayType(StringType,true),Some(List(StringType, StringType)))

scala> df.select(explode(dateList($"start",$"end")).as("dates")).show(30,false)
+----------------+
|dates           |
+----------------+
|02-05-2020 01:00|
|02-05-2020 02:00|
|02-05-2020 03:00|
|02-05-2020 04:00|
|02-05-2020 05:00|
|02-05-2020 06:00|
|02-05-2020 07:00|
|02-05-2020 08:00|
|02-05-2020 09:00|
|02-05-2020 10:00|
|02-05-2020 11:00|
|02-05-2020 12:00|
|02-05-2020 13:00|
|02-05-2020 14:00|
|02-05-2020 15:00|
|02-05-2020 16:00|
|02-05-2020 17:00|
|02-05-2020 18:00|
|02-05-2020 19:00|
|02-05-2020 20:00|
|02-05-2020 21:00|
|02-05-2020 22:00|
|02-05-2020 23:00|
|03-05-2020 00:00|
|03-05-2020 01:00|
|03-05-2020 02:00|
+----------------+

scala>
```

**Execution Time : Solution - 1**

```
scala> spark.time { spark.sql("SELECT explode(sequence(1588381200, 1588471200, 3600)) as date_col").withColumn("date_col", from_unixtime($"date_col")).show(5,false)}
+-------------------+
|date_col           |
+-------------------+
|2020-05-02 06:30:00|
|2020-05-02 07:30:00|
|2020-05-02 08:30:00|
|2020-05-02 09:30:00|
|2020-05-02 10:30:00|
+-------------------+
only showing top 5 rows

Time taken: 2122 ms
```

**Execution Time : Solution - 2**

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

spark.time {
val df = Seq(("02-05-2020 01:00","03-05-2020 02:00")).toDF("start","end")
// Creating UDF to get List of dates.
val dateList = udf((start:String,end: String) => {
      import org.joda.time._
      import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
      val st = DateTime.parse(start,DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"))
      val et = DateTime.parse(end,DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"))
      (0 to Hours.hoursBetween(st,et).getHours)
         .map(hour => st.plusHours(hour).toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")))
        .toList
})

df.select(explode(dateList($"start",$"end")).as("dates")).show(5,false)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

+----------------+
|dates           |
+----------------+
|02-05-2020 01:00|
|02-05-2020 02:00|
|02-05-2020 03:00|
|02-05-2020 04:00|
|02-05-2020 05:00|
+----------------+
only showing top 5 rows

Time taken: 548 ms

scala>
```

Comment: Should use native Spark function when available over UDF . In this case this can be done with native Spark. I don't think this is the correct/ best answer from that perspective and for readability.

Comment: spark function ```sequence``` is only available from ```spark 2.4.0+``` versions

Comment: The op hasn't said he's using 2.3.0

Comment: But even 2.3.0 the sequence step can easily be replaced by creating the same range of numbers/ unix time in scala with a range function and then creating a dataframe with it. This would result in a much more concise and readable code.

Comment: I have updated my answer you can check how much time it is taking each solution & there is no hard rules which says we should not use ```UDF```. Its upto us .. :)

Comment: also I liked your one line solution & upvoted .. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
df = (spark
      .sql(f"SELECT explode(sequence(1588381200, 1588471200, 3600)) as date_col")
      .withColumn('date_col', F.from_unixtime('date_col'))
     )

# Result dataframe
+-------------------+
|           date_col|
+-------------------+
|2020-05-02 01:00:00|
|2020-05-02 02:00:00|
|2020-05-02 03:00:00|
|2020-05-02 04:00:00|
|2020-05-02 05:00:00|
...
|2020-05-03 01:00:00|
|2020-05-03 02:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

`sequence(start, stop, step)` takes three parameters.

Find out the unix time for your start and end date (unix time are counted in seconds),
I used https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

1588381200 is unix time for 02-05-2020 01:00

1588471200 is unit time for 03-05-2020 02:00

3600 is the interval i.e. 1 hour = 3600 seconds

Answer (score 2):

Another approach which is not covered in other answers currently-

```scala
val startTimeStamp = "02-05-2020 01:00"
    val endTimeStamp = "03-05-2020 02:00"
    spark.range(1).selectExpr(
      s"""
        |explode(sequence(
        |      to_timestamp('$startTimeStamp', 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm'),
        |      to_timestamp('$endTimeStamp', 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm'),
        |      interval 1 hour
        |    )) as generated_timestamp
      """.stripMargin
    ).show(false)

    /**
      * +-------------------+
      * |generated_timestamp|
      * +-------------------+
      * |2020-05-02 01:00:00|
      * |2020-05-02 02:00:00|
      * |2020-05-02 03:00:00|
      * |2020-05-02 04:00:00|
      * |2020-05-02 05:00:00|
      * |2020-05-02 06:00:00|
      * |2020-05-02 07:00:00|
      * |2020-05-02 08:00:00|
      * |2020-05-02 09:00:00|
      * |2020-05-02 10:00:00|
      * |2020-05-02 11:00:00|
      * |2020-05-02 12:00:00|
      * |2020-05-02 13:00:00|
      * |2020-05-02 14:00:00|
      * |2020-05-02 15:00:00|
      * |2020-05-02 16:00:00|
      * |2020-05-02 17:00:00|
      * |2020-05-02 18:00:00|
      * |2020-05-02 19:00:00|
      * |2020-05-02 20:00:00|
      * +-------------------+
      * only showing top 20 rows
      */
```

Comment: Spark is lazy so there is only one dataframe created by the way. `selectExpr` adds the column to the existing dataframe namely `generate_timestamp` and then the same is getting projected. check the execution plan please :)